# Why are hyphens invalid in JS-like syntax for hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Going through Hartl's Rails tutorial, and he mentions that while:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "application", { media: "all",
                                 "data-turbolinks-track" => true }
```

is valid

```
stylesheet_link_tag "application", { media: "all",
                                 data-turbolinks-track: true }
```

is not valid because "invalid because of hyphens." Can anyone explain this further for me? Why do hyphens make this invalid?

Comment: @muistooshort sorry didn't notice the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colon hash syntax does not support all symbols. Sometimes you must use hashrockets. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no/8675314#8675314).

`foo: true` boils down to `:foo => true`. In symbols, dashes must be escaped like that: `:'foo-bar'`. `foo-bar: true` is not valid because `:foo-bar => true` is not, too.

Comment: thanks---the linked explanation was definitely helpful. sounds like a lot of this is idiosyncratic.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find any answer on SO helpful don't hesitate and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the hyphens could be interpreted as minus sign, and that's why variable names can't contain hyphens. I think you could do this though: `:'data-turbolinks-track' =>`

I know if you want to puts strange character in a symbol, you can do this: `:'a-symbol^with#weird+:symbols'`. That basically means wrap symbols in a string, except the ':' when putting unusually characters in them.

Comment: No, `'data-turbolinks-track': true` will not work. `:'data-turbolinks-track' => true`, however, will work.

Comment: @muistooshort Is this Rails/js/json specific behaviour? I know only basics of Rails but, as fair I remember, `'text': true` is equivalent of `:'text' => true`. I think it was added around version 1.9, so both codes you have written should be valid in the Rails 3/4.

Comment: No, the syntaxes are not at all equivalent: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/479863), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675314/479863), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796799/479863), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694676/479863). Nothing to do with Rails either, just a half-baked named argument implementation in Ruby.