# Ruby: colon before vs after

Tags: ruby

When using Ruby, I keep getting mixed up with the `:`.

Can someone please explain when I'm supposed to use it before the variable name, like `:name`, and when I'm supposed to use it after the variable like `name:`?

An example would be sublime.

Comment: Thought this was a dupe at first, but all the questions I can find don't seem to mention the newer Hash syntax { key: val }

Comment: Isn't this covered by these questions? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8675206/479863), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10004158/479863), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8675206/479863), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8796358/479863), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9694209/479863)

Comment: To varying degrees, but yes to the first one in particular.  Didn't find that one when I was looking.

Comment: This should also be useful: [What is the colon operator in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337897/what-is-the-colon-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: Ruby 2.1 introduced 'required keyword arguments', which are defined with a trailing colon. See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments
That's whay this question was deemed as 'duplicate' mistakenly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are welcome for both, while creating `Hash` :

```
{:name => "foo"}
#or
{name: 'foo'} # This is allowed since Ruby 1.9
```

But basically `:name` is a [`Symbol`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html) object in Ruby.

From [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html)

> Hashes allow an alternate syntax form when your keys are always symbols. Instead of

```
options = { :font_size => 10, :font_family => "Arial" }
```

You could write it as:

```
options = { font_size: 10, font_family: "Arial" }
```

Comment: Ok, and when passing a named parameter to a function, which do I use: `Model.create(:name "John")` or `Model.create(name: "John")`. They're not interchangeable, are they?

Comment: `Model.create(:name "John")` is not valid.. `Model.create(:name =>"John")` is valid.

Comment: Crystal clear now, thanks for the examples!

Comment: The 1.9 syntax, borrowed from JavaScript, does lead to a bit of confusion: `{ foo: :foo }` is equivalent to `{ :foo => :foo }` even though it looks like two different things.

Comment: @tadman I forgot to mention. Thanks for mentioning here.

Comment: The JavaScript style notation requires that symbols be [valid labels](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694676/479863) so you can't use it with all sorts of valid symbols like `:$set` (quite common when working with MongoDB), `:'where is pancakes house?'`, `:[]`, `:@x`, ...

Comment: @muistooshort Your *knowledge* is equivalent to a depth of *sea*.

Comment: No, this is just my Ruby pet peeve. This has got to be the most confusing thing Matz ever did to Ruby :(

Comment: @muis waytooshort, let's start a list.  How about `singleton class` vs. `metaclass` vs. `anonymous class`, `reduce` vs `inject` etc.?

Comment: Arup, please clarify your comment address to @muistooshort.  Which sea?  Greatest depth is 6,946 meters for the Carribean Sea, a mere 14m for the Sea of Azov.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, could be 10,994 meters in the Mariana Trench…

Comment: @CarySwoveland :) ..

Comment: @dlu, I guess that depends on what Arup meant by "sea". If he meant the world ocean, the Mariana Trench would be appropriate; if he meant bodies of water that are regarded as seas (and generally have "sea" in their name), it would be the Carribean Sea. Regardless, we are agreed that mu is too short is a very deep thinker.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed, and that software types are very littoral (or not so) thinkers. Sorry, I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 72):

This has absolutely nothing to do with variables.

`:foo` is a `Symbol` literal, just like `'foo'` is a `String` literal and `42` is an `Integer` literal.

`foo:` is used in three places:

- as an alternative syntax for `Symbol` literals as the key of a `Hash` literal: `{ foo: 42 } # the same as { :foo => 42 }`
- in a parameter list for declaring a keyword parameter: `def foo(bar:) end`
- in an argument list for passing a keyword argument: `foo(bar: 42)`

Comment: This line 'as an alternative syntax for Symbol literals as the key of a Hash literal: { foo: 42 } # the same as { :foo => 42 }' ripped out all my questions. Thank you.

Comment: What does the syntax [without hash values](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/9ce66038647bc4ff63167fe9c74857a01acc0875/app/models/post_alert_observer.rb#L2), e.g. `observe :post_action, :post_revision` mean?

Comment: @DanDascalescu: This is a message send, sending the message `observe` to `self` with two arguments, `:post_action` and `:post_revision`.

Answer (score 11):

`:name` is a symbol. `name: "Bob"` is a special short-hand syntax for defining a Hash with the symbol `:name` a key and the string `"Bob"` as a value, which would otherwise be written as `{ :name => "Bob" }`.

Comment: `:$set` is also a symbol but `{ $set: 6 }` is a syntax error.

Comment: @muistooshort As per you `{ :$set => 6 }` is a safer way to play.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it after when you are creating a hash.

You use it before when you are wanting to reference a symbol.

In Arup's example, `{name: 'foo'}` you are creating a symbol, and using it as a key.

Later, if that hash is stored in a variable baz, you can reference the created key as a symbol:

`baz[:name]`

Comment: But you can't always use the JavaScript style notation when using symbols as keys in a Hash literal, `:$set => { ... }` for example.

Comment: This is true.  There are exceptions.  I thought the question was simply some examples.  Going to read the question again... :)

Comment: Thought I had mentioned JavaScript... But it was not I.