# Difference in ways to call partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am assuming this applies to other things as well, but this where I've noticed it the most in the tutorials I've gone through so far. Basically, what is the difference between:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/warning" %>
```

and

```
<%= render partial: "shared/warning" %>
```

Comment: Effectively no difference. Hash rockets are an older (pre-Rails 4) syntax, but still supported. If you're just now picking up Rails, stick with the newer syntax, since most of the [current examples and guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) will use that syntax.

Comment: Ahh okay. I'd seen it both ways, always seemed to do the same thing, just wanted to make sure there wasn't some odd nuanced difference I was unaware of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Colon before vs after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661857/ruby-colon-before-vs-after)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for a `Hash` literal in ruby is:

```
{ key => value }
```

The `key` can be any object, including a `Symbol`, eg.

```
{ :foo => "bar" }
```

Using a symbol for the keys in a hash became so popular, and so idiomatic in ruby that in ruby 1.9 an optional syntax was added for a hash created with symbol keys, and from there on the following is precisely equivalent to the above:

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

#### Update

Further to your specific use case, ruby also allows you to drop the `{}`s when passing the `Hash` as an argument to a method (as well as being able to drop the `()`s), so the following are equivalent:

```
foobar( { foo: "bar" } )
foobar( foo: "bar" )
foobar foo: "bar"
foobar :foo => "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per I know , both are same . And last one you mentioned is recommended .

Answer (score 0):

Both does the same thing and the second one is recommended.

You could also use `render` instead of `render :partial`

```
<%= render "shared/warning" %>
```

`render` is a shorthand for `render :partial`.
But `render` will not accept additional local variables for the partial via `:locals` hash, you need to use `render :partial` as following for that:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/warning", locals: { my_var: 'Hi!' } %>
```

In the shorthand syntax you can pass in local variables like this:

`<%= render "shared/warning", my_var: "Hi!" %>`

Comment: Actually, even with the shorthand syntax you can pass in local variables, just do them right in the arg list (rather than in a `:locals` hash, eg. `= render "shared/warning", my_var: "Hi!"`