# Using symbols as hash keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

When learning rails I am often confused when in some scenarios a colon is placed before a word and on other occasions it is placed after the word. I have been reading and rereading to try an understand this better and so far have determined that when a colon is placed before the word it is a symbol.

I thought I understood this until I read "[Agile Web Development with Rails 4 (Facets of Ruby), page 56](http://www.learnr.pro/content/44242-agile-web-development-with-rails-4-facets-of-ruby/56)".

Am I correctly understanding that a symbol has a colon before its name even when used as the key in a hash however there is an alternative syntax that places the colon after the symbol name in a hash?

Comment: Note that the JavaScript trailing colon style doesn't not always work even when you're using symbols as Hash keys. `{ :$set => { ... } }`, for example, is valid but `{ $set: { ... } }` is a syntax error.

Comment: You might be interested in [**Is Hash Rocket deprecated?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10004158/479863), [**How to create symbol (hash key) from association, using new ruby (1.9) hash syntax?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8796358/479863), and [**Supporting Ruby 1.9's hash syntax in Ruby 1.8**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9694209/479863) too. And check the *Related* sections in the sidebars for those questions for even more discussion of this confusing feature of Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. A symbol is always defined with the colon before the name

```
:foo
```

The original notation for the Hash with symbol keys was

```
{ :foo => "bar" }
```

However, since Ruby 1.9, there is an alternative notation that was designed to be more compact.

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

The two notations are equivalent. However, this is a specific Hash exception. The following is not a valid symbol declaration on its on

```
foo:
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. What I cannot understand is if the original notation was:
    { :foo => "bar" }
and there was a desire to shorten it why not make it:
    { :foo "bar" }

So in essence when I see a colon before a word I know it's a symbol and when I see a colon after a word I know it's still a symbol but just being used in a hash using the compact format. i.e.

    Model.where(:foo => 'bar').update_all(author: 'David')

Comment: The two notations are not equivalent since the symbols allowed with the JavaScript style are more limited than the symbols allowed with a hashrocket.

Comment: Thought I had this until I read the following in an example migration:

t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

So price, precision and scale are all symbols but the later two are using the compact notation within a hash??

Comment: and another example just to add to my confusion: <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 6 %>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you launch the Rails console, then run:

```
{ test: "ds"}.keys[0] == :test
```

You'll see it returns true